# How to access to a CSS class of a pre-build component

Tags: css, swiper.js

I'm working on my portfolio website and I'm doing it with Gatsby. I've imported a Swiper component, precisely a CubeEffect slideshow.

As I have my background black, I would like to change the Swiper Shadow to red (by default is black) but I'm struggling to access to swiper-cube-shadow::before className, because is an own swiper's className.

I've added css style to the Swiper component, to the SwiperSlide component but I don't know how to access to the swiper-cube-shadow component that should be at the same level of the  component and consequently to the className...

I cannot add a selector to a component that I don't know how to select, because is inside the Swiper component with is own name and If I create a new component with the same name will not modify the original component but just create a new one.

On the first link you have a picture of the HTML elements (I don't have the privilege to attach an image yet) with the <div class-name:'swiper-cube-shadow'> that I'm trying to customize.

```
<Swiper css={css `
 [css styles]
`}
    <SwiperSlide css={css`
 [css styles]
`}>
      <Dado2/>
   </SwiperSlide>
 </Swiper>
```

[class-name:swiper-cube-shadow::before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PJIl.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The code has been removed.

Comment: The point was not that you should remove information that is (in all likelihood) relevant to your question, but that you should present it _properly_ - in text form & formatted. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: ok, thanks for the info. I'll add the code structure now editing the question.

Comment: It's just a matter of adding the same selector (or a selector with higher specificity) after the plugin's CSS has loaded. Cascading stylesheets are called cascading for a reason ;)

Comment: Seems like you are using CSS modules... If I'm right, try writing swiper-specific codes in a global (normal) CSS file instead of CSS modules. Since CSS modules create a name like this `.swiper-slide_87jhdsfkj12`, you can't use it.